# Enable/disable swipe to dismiss at runtime

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on a wear app and I am able to enable/disable swipe to dismiss functionality by setting

```
 android:windowSwipeToDismiss
```

to `false/true` in extended style. There are two states of the screen I am showing in my activity. For each of these exclusive states, the swipe to dismiss feature need to be either enabled or disabled. I have not been able to do this.

I have searched a lot but I am unable to find the right solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SwipeDismissFrameLayout as your main layout and use that to control weather the activity can be dismissed or not. Having android:windowSwipeToDismiss set to false.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. On more thing I added was made main window background transparent and finish activity on dismissed.